# What does "O" stand for in this paper from 1961?

Tags: terminology

I'm currently reading "[Perceived Order in Different Sense Modalities](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1963-00179-001)" (Hirsh and Sherrick, 1961). In they repeatedly use the abbreviation "O" and I have no idea what it stands for. It seemed to have been in common use back in those days, but fallen out of favor since. Some usage examples:

- To investigate the limits of the ability to distinguish successive from simulateneous events, we need only a pair or series of events about which we can ask *O* whether there were one or two [...].
- The question for Exp. I was: how much time must intervene between two visual stimuli for *O* to report correctly the order in which they occur?
- Four trained *O*s, between 18 and 30 yr. old, were tested singly.

Obviously, *O* means something along the line of "subject" or "participant". However, I'm wondering what it stands for exactly. My best guess would be something like "observer".

Comment: I'd go with observer, too.  Unfortunately, the article's behind a paywall or I'd look closer.

Comment: I have zero familiarity with this field, but I found this (see point 2): https://dictionary.apa.org/observer . Someone else might be able to confirm if that applies to your context.

Comment: Observer. It seems so from the examples.