# What Does 'S' Stand for in a Research Report?

Tags: terminology

I'm reading a research report. I encountered several times 'S' which I don't know what it stands for.

Examples:

'The first directions to S were as follows.'

'After the record was played, S was asked to grade the music as a whole on a four-point scale.'

It's a study about *musical humor* and 30 college students were the subjects.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/178412/68109

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the paper you have quoted, *S* stands for a noun, probably *Subject* but possibly *Student*, and not a specific name like Stephen or Sally. This is evidenced by its use in the plural:

> The *Ständchen* was chosen for the purpose of detecting a bias in our *S*s toward finding humor... (p. 560)

And with a qualifier:

> Every *S* observed separately and in two sessions. (p. 560)

And with an article:

> If, upon being questioned an *S* was found to be already familiar with a given composition... (p. 561)

The paper does not explicitly say "S is for Subject," but first paragraph of the *Method and procedure* section starts out (emphasis mine):

> Thirty Sweet Briar College **students** recommended as 'musical' were **subjects** in our study. (p. 560)

Source:

Mull, H. K. (1949). A Study of Humor in Music. *The American Journal of Psychology, 62*(4), 560–566. https://doi.org/10.2307/1418560

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a stand-in for a name to preserve anonymity. It is, perhaps, an initial of one of the subjects, perhaps standing for something like "Stephen" or "Sally".

It is fairly common usage. It actually helps the author keep track of things, but doesn't reveal the names of research subjects.

Comment: I believe it is a stand-in for 'Subject', but I can't point to any evidence in support of this...

Comment: I also guessed S for "subject".

Comment: @avid, that is possible, but there is no reason not to spell out "subject". Also, I'd expect it to appear followed by a number, say S5, to distinguish subjects.